# GridView is not showing record

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show records in GridView depending on dropdownlist value

```
<asp:GridView ID="usersgrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
 <Columns >
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Occupation" HeaderText="Occupation"/>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is Dropdownlist from where user has to select Age range so that result can be shown according to selection

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" DataTextField="Age" DataValueField="Profile_ID"  runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" DataTextField="Age" DataValueField="Profile_ID"  runat="server" CssClass="validate[required]" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please select course"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I am fetching Age form database. Now after selecting when user clicks on Search button GridView must be filled with result.

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "select Profile_ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name, Age, Occupation from UserProfile where Age BETWEEN  " + ddl1.Text + "AND " + ddl2.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                usersgrid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                usersgrid.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

But GridView is not showing any record. Where is the mistake?

Comment: is there any error while usersgrid.DataBind(); use debugger

Comment: No there wasn't any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you forget to check the postback. So that your dropdownbox is resetting when you click the button. Try

```
if(!isPostBack)
   {
     //bind your dropdownbox
   }
```

on binding your dropdownbox contents.

Comment: I have used this in Page_Load.

Comment: of course.. Add if(!isPostBack) { // bind your dropdownbox here} inside your Page_Load event. Cut the binding part and put inside the if clause mentioned above..

Comment: Yes I have bounded my dropdownlist in if(!isPostBack)

Comment: Please put a break point to your dropdownbox selected value (ddl1.Text, ddl2.Text) and see whether it is holding the value after you initiate the databound to the grid.

Comment: You just gave me a clue. I was writing ddl1.Text instead of ddl1.SelectedItem.Text. and Now issue is resolved :)

Comment: Well.. Sometimes we miss the small part.. :p

Comment: Mostly Me. Well, Thanx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot a space in you SQL query right before the 'AND'?

`[...] + ddl1.Text + " AND " + ddl2.Text;`

Comment: I gave proper spaces but still no records.